# Why is my Worldbuilding picture not coming up?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I have 3 accounts (stack overflow, 3d printing and world building), but worldbuilding isn't coming up and my profile says i have only 2 accounts Why?

Comment: Please don't down vote, I am only 12

Comment: [If you are under 13 you are in violation of Stack Exchange's EULA](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61770/how-do-i-use-stack-exchange-if-im-under-13-years-old).Sorry. Other than that, we do not take age into account when voting.

Comment: I am 13 in 2 weeks

Comment: You may have accidentally created a new account and are unregstered on one of the sites. Have a look at this question and see if it helps you: [How can one link / merge / combine / associate two accounts / users? (Anonymous / unregistered / cookie, or OpenID / registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous). I hope you stick around, have fun!

Comment: @Anonymouse Downvotes work differently on Meta than on the main site. On Meta, downvotes are typically used in a manner similar to "I disagree with this", as opposed to "I think this is a bad post". Same mechanism, different meaning.

Comment: @Renan If you see something like that, don't downvote, but rather flag for moderator attention and highlight the problem. The poster's age has *zero* direct bearing on the quality of the post, so should not influence voting at all.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, I shut down the computer and it got fixed:)

Comment: Good that you found your solution. Please accept this answer as soon as the little green check mark under the score of this post comes up to show others that your problem has been solved.

Comment: @Secespitus There is a delay before one can accept a self-answer. I think it is 48 hours.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling That's why I mentioned "as soon as the little green check mark under the score of this post comes up". But thanks for mentioning the time, I should have looked that up. Anonymouse: For more information about what Michael mentioned you can look [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/352819)